# How to make Livedata not update whole list

Tags: android, android-livedata

So I've got an adapter, which is holding a list of objects that I'm displaying. I'm using the MVVP approach with LiveData and ViewModel that come with the android architecture framework.

In my fragment, I connect the livedata to the adapter:

```
    viewModel.getAlarms().observe(this, alarms -> {
        Timber.d("Updating alarm list");
        alarmAdapter.updateAlarms(alarms);
    });
```

And in my adapter, I update the list...

```
    void updateAlarms(List<Alarm> alarms){
        this.alarms = alarms;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

So even if I make a small change on a single item from the list (item update, item create, item delete..), the whole list will update. That messes up all of my animations. Is there a way to prevent that?

I don't want to copy everything, but as requested here's the bigger picture:
Fragment:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        // Get everything..
        viewModel.getAlarms().observe(this, alarms -> {
            Timber.d("Updating alarm list");
            alarmAdapter.updateAlarms(alarms);
        });
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.home_fbtn_add_alarm)
    void addAlarm(){
        viewModel.createAlarm(new Alarm(13,39));
    }

    private void onAlarmStatusChanged(int alarmId, boolean isActive){
        // TODO Make it so it doesn't update the whole list...
        viewModel.setAlarmStatus(alarmId, isActive);
    }

    private void onAlarmDeleted(int alarmId){
        this.showSnackbar(String.format("Alarm %s deleted", alarmId), clContainer);
        viewModel.deleteAlarm(alarmId);
    }
```

Adapter:

```
class AlarmsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmsAdapter.AlarmHolder> {

private List<Alarm> alarms;
private BiConsumer<Integer, Boolean> onStatusChange;
private Consumer<Integer> onDelete;

AlarmsAdapter(BiConsumer<Integer, Boolean> onStatusChange, Consumer<Integer> onDelete) {
    this.alarms = new ArrayList<>();
    this.onStatusChange = onStatusChange;
    this.onDelete = onDelete;
}

void updateAlarms(List<Alarm> alarms){
    this.alarms = alarms;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AlarmHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context parentContext = parent.getContext();
    int alarmLayoutId = R.layout.item_alarm;
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parentContext).inflate(alarmLayoutId, parent, false);

    return new AlarmHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AlarmHolder alarmViewHolder, int position) {
    Alarm alarm = alarms.get(position);
    alarmViewHolder.setAlarm(alarm);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return alarms == null ? 0 : alarms.size();
}

class AlarmHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.item_alarm_tv_time)
    TextView tvTime;

    @BindView(R.id.item_alarm_tv_repeat)
    TextView tvRepeat;

    @BindView(R.id.item_alarm_tv_punishments)
    TextView tvPunishment;

    @BindView(R.id.item_alarm_swt_active)
    Switch swtActive;

    @BindView(R.id.item_alarm_img_delete)
    ImageView imgDelete;

    @BindView(R.id.item_alarm_foreground)
    ConstraintLayout foreground;

    @BindView(R.id.item_alarm_background)
    RelativeLayout background;

    AlarmHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    void setAlarm(Alarm alarm){
        Timber.i("Setting alarm: %s", this.getAdapterPosition());
        boolean isActive = alarm.getActive();
        tvTime.setText(alarm.getTime());
        tvRepeat.setText(alarm.getRepetitionDays());
        tvPunishment.setText(alarm.getPunishments());
        swtActive.setChecked(isActive);
    }

    private void setStatus(boolean isActive) {
        AlphaAnimation animation;
        if(!isActive){
            animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.3f);

        } else {
            animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.3f, 1f);
        }
        animation.setDuration(300);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        this.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
        // TODO Make it so it doesn't update the whole list...

    }

    @OnCheckedChanged(R.id.item_alarm_swt_active)
    void onStatusClick(boolean checked) {
        onStatusChange.accept(getAdapterPosition(), checked);
        setStatus(checked);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.item_alarm_img_delete)
    void onDeleteClick() {
        onDelete.accept(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}}
```

And the LiveData:

```
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

private final AlarmRepository alarmRepository;
private LiveData<List<Alarm>> alarms;

public HomeViewModel(AlarmRepository alarmRepository) {
    this.alarmRepository = alarmRepository;
}

/**
 * Gets the Alarms' Observable...
 * @return Alarms' observable
 */
LiveData<List<Alarm>> getAlarms() {
    Timber.d("Fetching alarms..");
    if(alarms == null) {
        Timber.i("No alarms are cached. Going to DB!");
        alarms = alarmRepository.getAllAlarms();
    }
    return alarms;
}

/**
 * Deletes the selected
 * @param alarmPosition alarm to be deleted
 */
void deleteAlarm(int alarmPosition) {
    Timber.d("Deleting alarm %d", alarmPosition);

    getAlarmAtPosition(alarmPosition)
            .ifPresent(alarmRepository::deleteAlarm);
}

/**
 * Changes the status of the selected alarm
 * @param alarmPosition The selected alarm
 * @param status The new status
 */
void setAlarmStatus(int alarmPosition, boolean status){
    Timber.d("Alarm: %d is changing active status to %s", alarmPosition, status);

    getAlarmAtPosition(alarmPosition)
            .ifPresent(alarm -> alarmRepository.updateStatus(alarm, status));
}


/**
 * Gets the alarm at the selected position.
 * @param position The position of the alarm
 * @return The alarm of the selected position. Else returns empty.
 */
private Optional<Alarm> getAlarmAtPosition(int position){

    Optional<List<Alarm>> alarms =
            Optional.ofNullable(this.alarms)
                    .map(LiveData::getValue);

    if(!alarms.isPresent()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    try {
        return Optional.of(alarms.get().get(position));
    } catch (Exception e){
        Timber.e(e, "Could not get alarm at position: %d", position);
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}


/**
 * Creates a new alarm. If null, does nothing.
 * @param alarm The alarm to be saved in the DB
 */
void createAlarm(Alarm alarm) {
    Timber.d("Adding new alarm.");
    if(alarm == null) {
        Timber.w("Cannot save null alarm");
        return;
    }

    alarmRepository.createAlarm(alarm);
}
```

}

Comment: Additional info would be helpful: how your adapter looks (at least its base class), are you using paging, is `updateAlarms` part of your adapter?

Comment: Hopefully this is enough @ror

Comment: Ignore the TODO's..

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using ListAdapter (part of recyclerView library)

```
class AlarmsAdapter extends ListAdapter<Alarm , AlarmsAdapter.AlarmHolder> {
    public AlarmsAdapter(
        @NonNull ItemCallback<Feed> diffCallback) {
    super(diffCallback);
    }.....
}
```

pass this to `AlarmsAdapter`

```
private final ItemCallback<Alarm > diffCallback = new ItemCallback<Feed>() {
    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Alarm oldItem, @NonNull Alarm newItem) {
        return oldItem==newItem;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Alarm oldItem, @NonNull Alarm newItem) {
        return oldItem==newItem;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can't quite follow. Care to elaborate?